# Analysis Services on Web Edition

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need to install the SQL Server 2012 Web Edition on my web server for my web application and I would like to know if I can install the Analysis Services on this edition and create some cubes of my clients data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this: [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) my guess is that it is not supported and that you'll need a different (Enterprise, Business Intelligence or Standard) edition to run analysis Services.

Comment: Tks. So, I think my question is another one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638660/clients-reports-from-web-app