# Clients Reports from web app

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have an web app with some static reports that is running with SQL Server 2012 Web Edition and I dont want the impact of a report process on usage of the app.
So, I decide to split the database:

1. Database Master - With all data. Used for all web app precess, except the reports
2. Database X - With all data from the client X. Used only for report and updated every day.
3. Database Z - With all data from the client Z. Used only for report and updated every day.
4. Database Y - With all data from the client Y. Used only for report and updated every day.

There is no limitation number of database that could have. 
What would be the best way?
-Cubes with Analises Services? I think I cant use this solution with Web Edition.

-Snapshot databases? Maybe in another server?

-Another solution?

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem using the SSIS (Integration Services) with Visual Studio

- I create the Azure SQL databases with table that I want to public to my client
- In SSIS I created packages for each client with their connection to Azure database. Also created a variable with the client ID that will be used by the filters.
- Published the project in Integration Services Catalog and add JOBs to execute the packages every midnight.
- For my clients I give the Azure credential (read-only) that will be used in Excel PowerPivot

Here is a link to a good SSIS tutorial. It worth for who has similar problem or need to migrate/extract/transform data. You can also generate Excel sheets.

[SSIS tutorial with SQL Azure](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/84/posts/13234/how-to-use-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-to-migrate-data-from-sql-server-to-sql-azure-paras-d.aspx)